# How can invoke a function in Javascript automatically like jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, invoke

I've been trying to understand how jQuery works. Let's say for instance you would like to do something when an anchor tag is clicked. Take the code below for example:

```
$('.selector').click
```

The `"$"` References jQuery but then how does jQuery know that it is supposed to look for and find `('.selector')` in the DOM? Then how does jQuery automatically know to run the following method of `"click"` on the matched element?

Comment: jQuery is free software... Why don't you download it and study it...?

Comment: Your title doesn't match your questions

Comment: Look at the code of jQuery at https://github.com/jquery/jquery

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I have studied jQuery I have the uncompressed version but there's so much and seems hard to see what is actually going on. So what I did was included jQuery and ran some tests and to tell if the .on method was firing I placed a console.log('fired') but really didn't help much because as soon as the page loaded the log fired! I am more or less hoping someone could point me in the right direction rather than looking through and wasting hours deciphering through nearly 10k lines of code!

Comment: Then, ask on some jQuery developer's forum or mailing list, but explain them first what you have understood. Expect indeed to spend weeks of work to understand jQuery. And you are not wasting your time studying it; it is part of the learning process.

Comment: @David Actually it has to be automatically running some method within jquery. Unless I'm wrong, you can't use pure javascript and say $(element).click? Something somewhere within jQuery has to auto run and go find the element so that the click can even happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$` is a function. You're passing it the `('.selector')` argument. That's how it knows what to fetch.

It then returns a `jQuery` object populated with the DOM elements that were found. That `jQuery` object has methods on it.

When you call `.click()` on the jQuery object, it iterates through the matched DOM elements it's holding, and performs the expected operation.

---

Here's a *very* simple example.

```
var $ = function(selector) {
    return new jQuery(selector);
}

function jQuery(selector) {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    this.length = [].push.apply(this, elems);
}
jQuery.prototype.click = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
        console.log("clicking", i, this[i].nodeName);
    return this;
}
```

Comment: jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Z5KCb/

Answer (score 0):

It basically registers an event handler for that event on the elements that are selected.  The event handler is something your browser takes care of, it invokes the handler when it registers a click.  JQuery just sets it up in a way that's more user friendly.

Also note `click()` is different than `click(function(){})`, the first actually invokes the click as if you just mouse clicked the item, the second is actually an event handler that calls your function when a click is performed.

Comment: Not sure you really understand the question. He doesn't want to know what this does, he wants to know _how_ it works.